# Can't connect pieces MIT App Inventor

Tags: android, arduino, app-inventor

Title says it all, I'm trying to make a basic Android App to control an LED on Arduino board using this guide [here](http://randomnerdtutorials.com/how-to-use-app-inventor-with-arduino/) but I can't figure out how to connect ListPicker1.AfterPicking to BluetoothClient1.Connect address.  Any help?

Here's a picture for reference, the small piece with | is what I can't figure out:
http://www.instructables.com/files/deriv/FPK/8FWN/HD4VFWB1/FPK8FWNHD4VFWB1.LARGE.jpg

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can find a complete example how to connect an Android phone to an Arduino via Bluetooth [here](http://ai.kittywolf.net/index.php/BTArduinoLED1)
the main part you are looking for looks like that:

[image]

In your case it seems to be, that you are selecting MAC addresses in the listpicker? If yes, in the screenshot just replace the value `MACaddrofBTDevice` by your `Listpicker1.Selection`